# Testing code coverage for jRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, jruby

Just out of interest, are there any easy to setup and work with code coverage tools for jRuby-1.5.3 and jRuby-1.6.5:

1. Testing coverage (C0, C1, C2)
2. Performance (Memory use, memory leaking)
3. Best practices

That would be a great idea to write down your thought, as I'm trying to break through this for almost a week.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To question #1, so far as I know, code coverage for JRuby 1.6.x running in 1.9 mode is blocked on this open defect: [JRuby 6106](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6106)

If you're running in 1.8 mode, you should be able to use the [rcov](http://rubygems.org/gems/rcov) gem.